# Unable to delete files in USB

Tags: windows, usb, chkdsk

I am not able to delete files in my USB flash drive.

Technically, it looks like I deleted them at the time, but the the files seems to revive every time I reconnect the USB drive to my laptop. No warning signs or whatsoever pops up during the process.

FYI, I never used a backup/recovery utility program, and all of the permission option is allowed to everybody. Full virus/malware scan detected nothing.

Error-checking from windows couldn't find any problem - to be precise it's more like it turns off automatically after a few seconds.
On the other hand, cmd > chkdsk /f seems to work at first, but halts at 73% and shows an error message.

Are there some other ways to fix this problem other than formating the whole USB drive?

Comment: Get what data you can off it. Throw it away. Don't ever keep your only copy of any data on a USB stick or SD card. The fail-rate is alarming.

Answer (score 0):

Even formatting the whole USB wouldn't work in this case as it looks like a case of dead USB.

I've had many such USBs and thrown them away.